# Android support repository isn't showing in SDK Mananger

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I would love to install the Android support repository, but it is nowhere to be found on the Android SDK manager:

[image]

Could anybody help me to add it to my IDE? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Tools` menu in SDK Manager, choose **Manage Add-on Sites**.

In `Official Add-on Sites` tab, if the following url `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml` is present enable it. If its not there try to add in the 'User Defined Sites' tab